# Python Add Column With FIle Name Without For Each Loop

Tags: python, pyspark, azure-databricks

I am hoping there is a python mind out there that can help me.  This is my first project using databricks + Python so forgive this newbie question.

In Azure databricks, I am processing an entire set of files from a directory together into one data frame (to improve performance (as opposed to processing one file at a time).

I need to add the name of each file in the filePath as a data column to denote what file the row came from.  Using a for each loop to process each file individually takes too much time for the number of files I am reading and the other data manipulations required as part of this dataframe.

The file contains:

```
col1    col2          
John    Dutton       
Beth    Dutton
```

I expect the output to be:

```
col1    col2           record source
John    Dutton         /mnt/mypath/mysourcefile1 <--- this is the name of the file in the directory
Beth    Dutton         /mnt/mypath/mysourcefile2 <--- this is the name of the file in the directory
```

I tried this below but it didn't like it as File.Name is not in the actual files it is reading.

```py
filePath = '/mnt/mypath/'
dfReadFHIR_raw = spark.read.option("multiline","true").json(filePath).withColumn("RecordSource", file.name)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced the above and able to get the source file as column using  [`input_file_name()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.input_file_name.html)

These are my source JSON files in the storage account.

[image]

First, I got the list of files in the folder, then read the files using the list.

**My Code:**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import input_file_name

l=dbutils.fs.ls("/mnt/data/jsonfolder")
files_list=[]
for i in range(0,len(l)):
    files_list.append(l[i].path)#getting paths list
    
print("paths list : ",files_list)

df=spark.read.json(path=files_list).withColumn("FileName",input_file_name())
display(df)
```

**Output dataframe with file names:**

[image]

**NOTE:**

In the above my JSON files are not array of objects and that's why I have not used `multiline=True` while reading. If your JSON files are array of objects, use `multiline`.

`df=spark.read.option("multiline","True").json(path=files_list).withColumn("FileName",input_file_name())`